# How to Retain DataType After Pyspark Merge with Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have a Databricks Dataframe with the following Schema:

[image]

You will notice the Data Type for the CreatedOn field is a DateType()

However, after doing a merge and loading the data with the variable `lakeDataDrop`

```
lakeDataDrop = spark.read.format("delta").load(saveloc)
```

the Data Type changes to TimestampType()

[image]

Can someone explain why the Data Type changes to TimestampType()?

I would like the Data Type to remain as a DateType()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in your dataset that you're using for merge the corresponding column has the `timestamp` type, so if you have schema evolution enabled, then the type is promoted from `date` to `timestamp`. Solution would be to cast the column in the "updates" dataframe that you're using in merge to `date` before merge.